# Disabling iCloud backup, tmp directory and replacement of files in path

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdocumentdirectory

I currently save and read from disk on my application with these 2 methods I created:

```
func unarchiveWithFileName(fileName: String) -> AnyObject? {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String
    let path = "\(documentsDirectory)/\(fileName)"
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path)
}

func archiveObjectWithFileName(fileName: String, object: AnyObject) {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String
    let path = "\(documentsDirectory)/\(fileName)"
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(object, toFile: path)
}
```

And my application got rejected for "storing on user's iCloud", and I have a few questions.

I came across this function for disabling iCloud backup:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath:(NSString *) filePathString
{
    NSURL* URL= [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePathString];
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}
```

But what should I apply it on?

In addition, in my application I save temporary files which I replace all the time with new files. Apple told me I should save these on the `tmp` directory, but will my app get rejected if I save it on the documents directory?

And my last question is, as I've said in my last question, I replace files all the time. Apple mentioned I should make sure I delete the temporary files, but can I simply replace them at the path? For example:

`archiveObjectWithFileName("fn", NSString())`
and afterwards
`archiveObjectWithFileName("fn", UIImage())`

Will the file simply get replaced or I still need to remove it?